# Can't build next.js application on production server with varying error messages with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am facing a problem with my next.js application.

In fact, I'm trying to switch my application to my production server. Before that, I tested it on my local computer, where I could build it.

Then I moved it to my pre-production server, where again I was able to build it.

However, when I run the "yarn build" command on the production server, an error is generated.

Which is :

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`

> Build error occurred
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/paplar-auto.fr/web/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So I tried a "yarn add webpack" and then made a new build, and I then got this error :

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`

> Build error occurred
{ Error: Cannot find module 'next-compose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/paplar-auto.fr/web/next.config.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Whereas, I already have next-compose in my devDepencies (here is my package.json) :

```
{
  "name": "web-gp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "build-static": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start -p 8000",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build:svg": "svgr -d components/icons svg/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@artsy/fresnel": "^1.1.0",
    "@bootstrap-styled/v4": "^3.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@react-hook/window-size": "^3.0.6",
    "@svgr/cli": "^5.3.1",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-styled": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "2.6.10",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "next": "9.3.5",
    "next-fonts": "^1.0.3",
    "next-images": "^1.4.0",
    "nextjs-fonts": "^0.22.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.16.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
    "react-leaflet-div-icon": "^1.1.0",
    "react-leaflet-universal": "^2.2.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-papaparse": "^3.1.1",
    "react-responsive": "^8.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.26.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "standard-http-error": "^2.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "swiper": "^6.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.50.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/preset-typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.18",
    "@storybook/theming": "^5.3.18",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
    "eslint": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.3",
    "next-compose": "^0.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

I have already tried to move the packages mentioned in the errors from devDependencies to dependencies, but it does not change anything.

The errors of the missing packages vary, are not the same. Usually when I pass next-compose from devDependencies to dependencies, it tells me that typescript is missing, and when I then pass typescript from devDependencies to dependencies, it tells me again that next-compose is missing.

Anyway, I don't understand anything, does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check whether you are using `yarn install --production` or `npm install --production` since it seems as though your dev-dependencies are not installed. Alternatively you could upload a pre-built version of your application to your production server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. yarn --production does not work unfortunately. I tried to import a pre-built version, but unfortunately that doesn't work either because we are using pm2 (I confess I don't really understand in detail what it is really for, but I guess it more or less mimics the yarn start command and runs the site on port 8000, so I would need to be able to build on the server), my site still returns a 503 error.

Comment: Do you get the same errors when building the app locally with `yarn build`?

Comment: No, by building locally, I didn't have these mistakes. It turns out that as suggested above, some dependencies should not have been in the devDependencies but in the dependencies because when I built with ```yarn build --production=false``` on the production server it worked. So I made some modifications at this level and I could build.